# What is the difference between fork()!=0 and !fork() in process creation

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

Currently, I am doing some exercises on operating system based on UNIX. I have used the fork() system call to create a child process and the code snippet is as follows :

```
if(!fork())
{
   printf("I am parent process.\n");
}
 else
   printf("I am child process.\n");
```

And this program first executes the child process and then parent process.

But, when I replace `if(!fork()) by if(fork()!=0`) then the parent block and then child block executes.Here my question is - does the result should be the same in both cases or there is some reason behind this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think the result should be the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Are you saying when you use the second if statement you posted, it prints both the first and second string?

Comment: This is likely a spurious observation on your part; there's no absolute guarantee that the parent process will return to userland before the child process executes.

Comment: the first program executes child and then  parent but after replacing if(!fork()) then parent and then child executes.....I am wondering by the result.@JesusAdoboLuzon

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a question about `fork` but about the logic of the operators `!` and `!=`. If you really don't understand these, it might be too early to start using `fork`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There is no guaranteed order of execution.
- However, `if(!fork())` and `if(fork()!=0)` do give **opposite** results logically: if `fork()` returns zero, then `!fork()` is true whilst `fork()!=0` is false.

Also, from the man page for fork():

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So the correct check is

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == -1) {
     // ERROR in PARENT
} else if(pid == 0) {
     // CHILD process
} else {
     // PARENT process, and the child has ID pid
}
```

EDIT: As Wyzard says, you should definitely make sure you make use of pid later as well. (Also, fixed the type to be pid_t instead of int.)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really use either of those, because when the child finishes, it'll remain as a zombie until the parent finishes too.  You should either capture the child's pid in a variable and use it to retrieve the child's exit status:

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == -1)
{
  // Fork failed, check errno
}
else if (child_pid)
{
  // Do parent stuff...

  int status;
  waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
}
else
{
  // Child stuff
}
```

or you should use the "[double-fork trick](http://kasperd.net/~kasperd/comp.os.linux.development.faq#zombie)" to dissociate the child from the parent, so that the child won't remain as a zombie waiting for the parent to retrieve its exit status.

Also, you can't rely on the child executing before the parent after a fork.  You have two processes, running *concurrently*, with no guarantee about relative order of execution.  They may take turns, or they may run simultaneously on different CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

`!fork()` and `fork() == 0` both behave in the same way.

The condition itself cannot be the reason the execution sequence is any different.
The process is replicated, which means that child is now competing with parent for resources, including CPU. It is the OS scheduler that decides which process will get the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the parent and child get to their respective `printf()` statements is undefined.  It is likely that if you were to repeat your tests a large number of times, the results would be similar for both, in that for either version there would be times that the parent prints first and times the parent prints last.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence in which child and parent processes are being execute is determined by the scheduler. It determines when and for how long each process is being executed by the processor. So the sequence of the output may vary for one and the same program code. It is purely coincidental that the change in the source code led to the change of the output sequence.
By the way, your printf's should be just the other way round: if fork() returns 0, it's the child, not the parent process.

See code example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29. The German version of this article (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28Unix%29) contains a sample output and a short discusion about operation sequence.